# Is it valid to include additional predictors into principal component regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pca

I performed a PCA on some data related to habitat (different types of vegetation cover, soil water etc.), but there were some variables that I did not include in the PCA because they were not strongly correlated with any of the other variables. I selected the first three principal components from the PCA whose eigenvalues were above 1.

Now I want to run a multiple regression to analyse what variables will predict bird density. Is it valid to include my three principal components as well as the variables that I did not include in the PCA into this regression?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  Sounds fine to me.

And welcome to the site. I deleted your sig line (the site adds it automatically) and edited your post

Comment: Also see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323739/